# KML Entity Replacement in BalloonStyle Fails in GoogleMaps, But Not GoogleEarth

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-earth

Spent way too many hours debugging KML from within GEarth vs. Google Maps.
Can someone give me a hint on why the following 'Entity Replacement' below works fine in GE but fails in GMaps.

I ran XMLValidate and the file is fine, but the tags in [CDATA] don't get replaced by GoogleMaps API, only in GEarth. I read the Best Practices KML docs on [BalloonStyle entity replacement](http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata#entityreplacement), and the mind-numbing description in the [OGC KML 2.2 standard](http://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=27810) and tuned and trimmed the file, but I'm still stumped. I can't get Entity Replacement to work in GMaps API in the case below.

Any ideas?
-Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
        <name>ParcelsJoinedx.kml</name>
        <Style id="outline">
            <PolyStyle>
                <color>00ff0000</color>
                <fill>1</fill>
                <outline>1</outline>
            </PolyStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <bgColor>ffffffff</bgColor>
                <text>
                <![CDATA[
                    <head>
                    <title></title>
                    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
                    <!-- TD{font-family: Arial; font-size: 9pt;} --->
                    </STYLE>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                      <table >
                      <tr><td valign='top'><font color="#aa0000">$[ParcelJoined/Location/displayName]:</font></td><td>$[ParcelJoined/Location]</td>
                      <tr><td><font color="#aa0000">$[ParcelJoined/ParcelID/displayName]:</font></td><td>$[ParcelJoined/ParcelID]</td>
                     </tr></table>
                     </body>
                     ]]>
                 </text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
        <Schema name="ParcelJoined" id="ParcelJoinedID">
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Name"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Description"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Location">
                <displayName><![CDATA[<b>Location</b>]]></displayName>
            </SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="ParcelID">
                <displayName><![CDATA[<b>ParcelID</b>]]></displayName>
            </SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Zone"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="AssessArea"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Owner"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="CoOwner"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Address1"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Address2"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="City"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="State"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="ZIP"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="AcctNum"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="YearBuilt"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="LandValue"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="BldgValue"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="OtherValue"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="TotalValue"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="MainBldgDesc"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="StateCode"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="SaleDate"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Rooms"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Beds"></SimpleField>
            <SimpleField type="string" name="Baths"></SimpleField>
        </Schema>
        <Folder>
            <name>ParcelJoinedFldr</name>
            <Placemark>
                <styleUrl>#outline</styleUrl>
                <ExtendedData>
                    <SchemaData schemaUrl="#ParcelJoinedID">
                        <SimpleData name="Location">68 WALCOTT AVE</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="ParcelID">9-459</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Zone">R40$39</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="AssessArea">3.72 AC</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Owner">CXXX, CXX R ET</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="CoOwner">CXXX, GLXXA G</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Address1">32 EAST 88TH STREET</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Address2"></SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="City">NEW YORK</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="State">NY</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="ZIP">10021</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="AcctNum">2421</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="YearBuilt">1910</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="LandValue">2036060</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="BldgValue">479800</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="OtherValue">1500</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="TotalValue">2517360</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="MainBldgDesc">CONVNTL</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="StateCode">1100 - SEASONAL &amp; BEACH</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="SaleDate">04/07/1995</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Rooms">0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Beds">0</SimpleData>
                        <SimpleData name="Baths">4 Full / 0 H</SimpleData>
                    </SchemaData>
                </ExtendedData>
                <Polygon>
                    <outerBoundaryIs>
                        <LinearRing>
                            <coordinates>-71.363000752291924,41.489279023867283 -71.364928267362686,41.489246551445632 -71.364928271377551,41.48924655145035 -71.366127398895557,41.489226333780891 -71.366980322431843,41.489211945621989 -71.366980559667908,41.489218729506135 -71.366992415755973,41.489658359975031 -71.363335128398276,41.489691230204564 -71.36332242991972,41.489681182960041 -71.36320151947757,41.489583338563875 -71.363080572769988,41.489488329510586 -71.363012929798629,41.48940065703426 -71.363000855378388,41.489285011997865 -71.363000752291924,41.489279023867283</coordinates>
                        </LinearRing>
                    </outerBoundaryIs>
                </Polygon>
            </Placemark>
        </Folder>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that it probably will work if you use simple `<ExtendedData>` and `<Data>` elements to provide the data, as well as or rather than `<Schema>` and `<SchemaData>` elements.

From looking at it, do you even need schema data? Are you using the KML in some other application that requires the data as typed strings?

Google Earth and Google maps ignore the type data, so it is just bloating your kml if it doesn't have some other purpose for you.

The first half of the document you linked to deals with this.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I removed all <Schema> and <SchemaData>, replacing it with <ExtendedData> and <Data>, and the _Entity Replacement_ now works. But it's definitely not ideal. I have thousands of <SchemaData> elements that are created as automated output from ogr2ogr from a Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb). Apparently I have to restructure the automated output of ogr2ogr... Awkward.

Comment: And... It seems strange that the examples in [Google's Developer's Guide](http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata#entityreplacement) directions on Entity Replacement using <Schema> and <SchemaData> would be incorrect or at least discouraged. Is not the point of a 'Schema' to separate the structure (typed fields) from the data itself, and a desirable goal in itself?

Comment: I just confirmed that Google Developers Guide example I cited above fails - GMaps doesn't replace the entity tags:   http://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.intelliskills.com%2Fgis%2Ftest5.kml

Comment: As I see it the guide you reference gives two separate examples. One for `simple data` types and one for `typed data` using a schema. The schema example is there to show you how to provide typed data to applications that use/require it. However Google Earth and Google Maps do not need or use typed data. I have always had issues with using the  <SchemaData> element in anything other that a handlfull of desktop GIS applications. I just don't think Google web maps supports it at all (although I am not 100% sure about this, it is simply from testing it myself...)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about why this doesn't work in Google Maps: both `<Schema>` and `<SchemaData>` are officially unsupported by the Google Maps API. `<Data>` is fully supported and `<ExtendedData>` is partially supported ([reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements)).

The reference provides a table detailing the KML features supported by the API. Here are the relevant rows:

```
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
|  KML element   | Supported in the API? |         Comment            |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
| <BalloonStyle> | partially             | only <text> is supported   |
| <Data>         | yes                   |                            |
| <ExtendedData> | partially             | untyped <Data> only, no    |
|                |                       | <SimpleData> or <Schema>,  |
|                |                       | and entity replacements of |
|                |                       | the form $[dataName] are   |
|                |                       | not supported.             |
| <Schema>       | no                    |                            |
| <SchemaData>   | no                    |                            |
+----------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+
```

In case the link breaks it is the "Supported KML elements" section of the "KML and GeoRSS" guide in the Google Maps JavaScript API developer docs.