# Entity replacement not working in a KML/XML file, how do I use this data?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

basically I want to put information into a balloon in Maps API, this is the [KML file](http://codeshare.io/gC7h0), the data is stored using SimpleData tags, and I am trying to access to it from the BalloonStyle text tag.

But it doesn't work, in the baloon is displayed simply $[something]. After some research, I discovered [Entity replacement may not be supported anymore by SimpleData tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731428/kml-entity-replacement-in-balloonstyle-fails-in-googlemaps-but-not-googleearth).

So how do I manage the data? I got the data from ogr2ogr conversion from a shapefile and I don't know how to manage its output to make it use ExtendedData and Data tags.

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `<SchemaData><SimpleData>` with `<Data><value>` elements with a text editor preferably one that can perform regular expression replacements on searches such as [NotePad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/).

You start with this:

```
<ExtendedData>
  <SchemaData schemaUrl="#biblioteche">
        <SimpleData name="INDIRIZZO">VIA SAN VITTORE, 21</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="TIPOLOGIA">BIBLIOTECHE</SimpleData>
        ...
        <SimpleData name="ID">0</SimpleData>
  </SchemaData>
</ExtendedData>
```

And need to convert to this form:

```
<ExtendedData> 
    <Data name="INDIRIZZO">
        <value>VIA SAN VITTORE, 21</value>
    </Data>
    <Data name="TIPOLOGIA">
        <value>BIBLIOTECHE</value>
    </Data>
        ...
    <Data name="ID">
        <value>0</value>
    </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

Globally make the following replacements (in this order):

| # | Find what | Replace with |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | `<SchemaData schemaUrl="#biblioteche">` |  |
| 2. | `</SchemaData>` |  |
| 3. | `<SimpleData` | `<Data` |
| 4. | `(<Data name=".*?">)` | `\1<value>` |
| 5. | `</SimpleData>` | `</value></Data>` |

Steps 1 and 2 have an empty target such that you delete the element.
Step 4 is the only step that needs to be done as a regular expression.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20140809a.kml)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That should do it! Didn't know you could do that, [it works!](http://websiteprova.cloudvent.net/)

Comment: This didn't work for me at first until I deleted all the accompanying BalloonStyle and Schema elements. And then it worked! Thank you!